# how to overwrite value filled with POST

Tags: django, django-forms, render

I'm trying to pass list of ids into hidden field:
the POST result is:

```
POST in add_document:<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['xxx', 'xxx'],  'person_ids': ['15129', '15161', '15177', '15217'], 'submit': ['Submit']}>
```

views.py:

```
(...)
   add_document_form = DocumentForm(request.POST or None, context = context, initial={'person_ids': '1'})
   context['add_document_form'] = add_document_form
   print(add_document_form.fields['person_ids'].initial)

   html_template = loader.get_template('backend/' + context['load_template'])
   return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))

(...)
```

forms.py:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
#    person_ids = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget = forms.HiddenInput())
    person_ids = forms.CharField(widget = forms.HiddenInput())   
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = kwargs.pop('context', None)
        super(DocumentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(self.fields['person_ids'].initial)
        self.fields['person_ids'].initial = '2'
        print(self.fields['person_ids'].initial)
```

But whatever I do - finally I got

```
<input type="hidden" name="person_ids" value="15217" id="id_person_ids">
```

Django totally ignores my initial settings... (while print always printing the correct values...

My best solution would be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="person_ids" value="['15129', '15161', '15177', '15217']" id="id_person_ids">
```

Changing widget to TextField changes nothing. The value of person_ids is still '15217'

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that `DocumentForm(request.POST`) is different than `DocumentForm(initial=request.POST)`....

so the solution is:

```
  if 'take_action' in request.POST:
       add_document_form = DocumentForm(context = context, initial = request.POST)
    else:
       add_document_form = DocumentForm(request.POST or None, context = context)
```